# Excel formula to calculate next month due date based on week and day of current month date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The input lets say is 1/10/2019 which is 2nd week Thursday. Can we have an excel formula which will output 2/14/2019

Comment: Your weeks, Which day are they based.  To me the 7th is still the first full week of Feb.

Comment: In that case it should return 2/14/2018

Comment: Can you give a few more examples? one data point isn't sufficient to figure out the rule you want

Comment: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/04/how-to-automatically-calculate-a-specific-day-of-a-month/

Comment: I think this needs more detail. What should 1/31/19 return, for example? It's in the 5th week of January, but February only has 4 weeks (disregarding leap years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,2+7*(INT(DAY(TODAY())/7)+1))-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,8-WEEKDAY(TODAY())))
```

[image]